# Capture the output of ONLY stdout in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

**PYTHON VERSION - 3.5.2** **OS - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**

I am currently using both stdout and print statements to write to the terminal.
I want to capture the output of ONLY sys.stdout.write command and not the print commands
So for eg if my code is -

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("Hello")
print("PRINT")
```

I want to capture only "Hello" and not "PRINT".

I am currently using this :

```
x = subprocess.run(['python3 test.py'] , shell = True , stdout = subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

which gives me this output:

```
['HelloPRINT', '']
```

Comment: `print()` uses `sys.stdout.write()` to display text. But suproccess see only text send by system and it doesn't know what you used to send text to system.

Comment: `print` writes to `sys.stdout` by default. You can, however, override this behavior in the `file` argument of the `print` function.

Comment: you can only redirect `print()` to file or `stderr` but you have to do it in code `print("Print", file=sys.stderr)`

Comment: So when I redirect it to `sys.stderr` what happens to the text ?

Comment: when you will run it in console/terminal then you will see all text - stdout` and `stderr` - but subprocess will get only `stdout` because you set only `stdout = subprocess.PIPE`

Comment: redirecting it to `stderr` solved my purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print()` uses `sys.stdout.write()` to display text .

Besides `suproccess` see only text send by system and it doesn't know what you used to send text to system.

You can only in code redirect `print()` to `sys.stderr`

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("Hello")
print("PRINT", file=sys.stderr)
```

and then you will still see all text when you run in console but you will get only `sys.stdout` when you use `subprocess`

You will also get only `stdout` in file if you use in console

```
python script.py > stdout.txt
```

or you redirect to other program

```
python script.py | sort
```

Instead of `print(... ,file=sys.stderr)` you can also use `sys.stderr.write("PRINT\n")` but you have to add `"\n"` at the end manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this because `print()` uses `sys.stdout.write()` internally. The following REPL session illustrates this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> class StdoutProxy:
...  def write(self, text):
...   return len(text) # do nothing
...
>>> sys.stdout = StdoutProxy()
>>> print("Hello!")
>>> sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__  # reset stdout to its original state
>>> print("Hello!")
Hello!
```

Comment: I redirected the output of print to `sys.stderr`. That solved my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own version of the `print` function like this:

```
import sys

def get_my_print(file=sys.stdout):
    _original_print = print
    def my_print(*objects, sep='', end='\n', file=file, flush=False):
        _original_print(*objects, sep='', end='\n', file=file, flush=False)
    return my_print

original_print = print
print("Redirect print to stderr...")
print = get_my_print(sys.stderr)

print("Print some numbers...")
for x in range(10):
    print(x)

print = original_print
print("Done.")
```

**Console**

```
$ python3 redirect_print.py 1> /dev/null
Print some numbers...
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```